# CSV file_reading datetime

Tags: csv, numpy, datetime

I have a csv file, and it has time column with format:
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

I want to plot other columns as a function of time. So i need to define "time". I have assigned to each time, a number, which is yyyymmddhhmmss.

However, it generates a jump between numbers, whenever date, or month or year chanegs.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you please share your code. As it stands the question is not specific enough so there are multiple solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Fist you should format correctly. Pandas is aware of the object datetime but when you use some of the import functions it is taken as a string. So what you need to do is make sure the column is set as the datetime type not as a string.

```
df['date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Now you can use the plot function or whatever in matplotlib. After plotting you should call

```
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

to get the date ticks to work

Comment: hi, thanks. I am actually reading the data with numpy and not panda. csv = np.genfromtxt('train.csv', delimiter=",")   how can i do this with numpy?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you use pandas. It will save you the bugs in the long run. Use pandas.read_csv